# Speed up image coloring with ReplaceImageValue

Tags: performance-tuning, image-processing

I have about `200000` rgb-images of such format (`2160*577 pixels`):

[image]

I want to colorize in each image some parts in white color:

To do so I am using the following code (`i1` is the `source image`, `i2` the `colored image`):

```
i2 = ReplaceImageValue[i1, {All, 1 ;; 20} -> White];
i2 = ReplaceImageValue[i2, {All, 557 ;; 577} -> White];
i2 = ReplaceImageValue[i2, {1 ;; 20, All} -> White];
i2 = ReplaceImageValue[i2, {2141 ;; 2160, All} -> White];
i2 = ReplaceImageValue[i2, {701 ;; 740, All} -> White];
i2 = ReplaceImageValue[i2, {1421 ;; 1460, All} -> White]
```

which needs about `6 sec` for a single image.

The result is:

[image]

So, if I want to do that for all the images I would need to wait for `1.2*10^6 sec` which are more than `13 days`.

Is there a way to make my code much faster?

Comment: Are the replacements applied to all images, or are there different replacements for different images?

Comment: The replacements are exactly the same for all images

Comment: If you are just trying to break the image up in three separate equal-sized rectangles separated by white strips, take a look at [`ImagePartition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePartition.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a version that should be superior to your attempt. I'm using `ImagePartition` (as already suggested by m_goldberg) to rip your original image apart at 1/3 of the image width. After that you use a negative `ImagePad` to remove 20 pixel and again a positive `ImagePad` to add a 20 pixel white border.

For processing a large number of images, it definitely help to do this in parallel. Remember to make everything in parallel: The importing, the splitting and the exporting.

```
splitImage[img_] := ImageAssemble[
  ImagePad[ImagePad[#, -20], 20, 1] & /@ 
   Flatten@ImagePartition[img, ImageDimensions[img]/{3, 1}]]

img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCScO.png"];
splitImage[img]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.016326, Null} *)
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Without taking importing time of the images into account this needs about 55 minutes for all your 200.000 images.

Comment: 200,000 images ...

Comment: @kale Fixed. It was 200.000 images.

Comment: dear halirutan, the code is not coloring the left 20 pixels of each of the 3 sub images - compare e.g. the left output image in my case with your output. The two gaps around the center image should have 40 pixels white space  ...

Comment: @MilenkoRubin-Zuzic I just saw that you make a white border completely around each sub-image. I fixed the code and now it's even faster. I compared my output image with yours and it seems to be identical.

Comment: dear halirutan, perfect ... extremely fast (with read/saving) ... thanks

Comment: @ halirutan: "Remember to make everything in parallel: The importing, the splitting and the exporting." Can you give an example to that?

Answer (score 4):

You can apply your transformation to a black image of the same dimension to create a mask. When you add this mask to one of your images the black areas of the mask will not affect them, and the white areas will make the color channel values in those areas of the images one or larger. However, those values will then be truncated back to 1, giving you the result you want. Thank you to halirutan for realizing that the performance is better if you specify "Bit" in `Image`.

```
mask = Image[ConstantArray[0, Reverse@ImageDimensions[img]], "Bit"];
mask = ReplaceImageValue[mask, {All, 1 ;; 20} -> White];
mask = ReplaceImageValue[mask, {All, 557 ;; 577} -> White];
mask = ReplaceImageValue[mask, {1 ;; 20, All} -> White];
mask = ReplaceImageValue[mask, {2141 ;; 2160, All} -> White];
mask = ReplaceImageValue[mask, {701 ;; 740, All} -> White];
mask = ReplaceImageValue[mask, {1421 ;; 1460, All} -> White]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCScO.png"];
ImageAdd[img, mask]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
ImageAdd[img, mask] // AccurateTiming
(* Out: 0.0325975 on my computer; 0.0117959 on halirutan's computer *)
```

halirutan's solution on my computer:

```
splitImage[img]; // AccurateTiming
(* Out: 0.0151506 *)
```

If your computer supports Cuda you can parallelize `ImageAdd` on the GPU easily by using `CUDAImageAdd`.

Comment: "halirutan's solution is faster though"... this is because you don't try hard enough! Check this out: `Import["http://goo.gl/NaH6rM"]["http://i.stack.imgur.com/VuZoL.png"]` +1

Comment: @halirutan Thank you, it's slower on my computer than yours but it's still a big a improvement. I added it to the answer.

Comment: I wonder: how about using `SparseArray[]` to generate the height values and then converting it to an `Image[]` for the mask?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. It doesn't improve the speed.